Adding a new field to task_struct - stuck on booting
I added a new field to the task_struct and also 2 very basic syscalls the set and get this field.
Now when I try to boot the VM (I am using Linux 4.15.18  Ubuntu on VirtualBox) I get the following message:
madam: no arrays found in config file or automatically (repeating many times)
gave up waiting for root file system device.
alert! uuid=xxxx does not exist, dropping to a shell!
I really don't understand what could I have done to cause this.
Those are all the changes that I have made:
in include/linux/sched.h:
struct task_struct{
volatile long state;
int new_field;  //my addition
...
}

in include/linux/init_task.h:
#define INIT_TASK(tsk) \
{
INIT_TASK_TI(tsk)  \
.state = 0, \
.new_field = 0, \  //my addition
...
}

I also added my syscalls to include/linux/syscalls.h and to arch/x86/entry/syscalls/syscall_64.tbl
but I don't think this is what causing the problem/

In INIT_TASK() it appears that you have a syntax error (missing value) for the .new_field.

It was just a typing error in this question, fixed it

Did you rebuild and reinstall all modules and the initramfs?

I am very new to this, so I am not exactly sure what I did. I ran those commands: " make -j $(nproc)" and than " sudo cp -f arch/x86/boot/bzImage / boot/vmlinuz-4.15.18-custom" and finally "sudo reboot"

The system will be trying to load old modules that will be incompatible with the kernel if they access struct task_struct values. If the kernel has been configured with CONFIG_MODVERSIONS, it should refuse to load the modules, otherwise, it may load them but it is likely to crash because structure members are at the wrong offsets. You need to do a full install of the kernel along with its modules and initial ramdisk (if using an initial ramdisk).

Update question with new data (instead of responding with it in the comment) like you did for my comment.  You do that for Nate's comment as well.
